# how to implement a long click listener on a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

I want to add `OnLongClickListener` on my list view. Whenever the user long press the item in list some action should be performed, But my code does not catch this listener. Please let me know where I am going wrong. The similar code works for `setOnItemClickListener` very well.

Here is the code :

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                    int index, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Log.d("in onLongClick");
                 String str=listView.getItemAtPosition(index).toString();

                 Log.d("long click : " +str);
                return true;
            }
});
```

Comment: Have you remembered to add "implements OnItemLongClickListener" to your class declaration?

Comment: see in xml whether long click is enable?

Comment: Maybe you have a Gesture Listener or something like this that is capturing the long press and consuming it.

Answer (score 335, accepted):

You have to set **setOnItemLongClickListener()** in the ListView:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

The XML for each item in the list (should you use a custom XML) must have `android:longClickable="true"` as well  (or you can use the convenience method `lv.setLongClickable(true);`). This way you can have a list with only some items responding to longclick.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Be sure to call `lv.setLongClickable(true);` also.

Comment: This didn't work for me. But this does: `lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {...`

Comment: somehow adroid:longClickable="true" is default. I'm using API 19. So I didn't need to specify it at all.

Comment: Android sets longClickable=true when setting the listener.

Comment: what value is stored in long id ? in public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id

Answer (score 28):

If your ListView **row** item refers to a separate XML file, be sure to add `android:longClickable="true"` to that layout file in addition to setting `setOnItemLongClickListener()` to your ListView.

Comment: that's true...but how about the background selected color, do we need to write the code too ... @Jonathan ?

Answer (score 15):

or try this code:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                    int index, long arg3) {

    Toast.makeText(list.this,myList.getItemAtPosition(index).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this above code will work on LongClicking the listview, not the individual items.

why not use [`registerForContextMenu(listView)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29). and then get the callback in OnCreateContextMenu.

For most use cases this will work same.

Answer (score 2):

In xml add

```
<ListView android:longClickable="true">
```

In java file

```
lv.setLongClickable(true)
```

try this setOnItemLongClickListener()

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                //final String category = "Position at : "+pos;
                final String category = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+category,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("category", category);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "long clicked, "+"pos: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

also don't forget to in your xml  `android:longClickable="true"` or if you have a custom view add this to your custom view class `youCustomView.setLongClickable(true);`

here is the output of the code above
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried most of these answers and they were all failing for TextViews that had autolink enabled but also had to use long press in the same place!

I made a custom class that works.

```
public class TextViewLinkLongPressUrl extends TextView {

    private boolean isLongClick = false;

    public TextViewLinkLongPressUrl(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewLinkLongPressUrl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewLinkLongPressUrl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(text, type);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && isLongClick) {
            isLongClick = false;
            return false;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            isLongClick = false;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            isLongClick = false;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performLongClick() {
        isLongClick = true;
        return super.performLongClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for cardView and will work the same for listview inside adapter calss, within `onBindViewHolder()` function

```
holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the adapter, you can simply do this:

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Long pressed on item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    listView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Definitely does the trick.