# ListView ItemClick ItemLong Click Issue android

Tags: android

I have a list view in which I have implemented both onItemClick and onItemLongClick.
The list view row is custom where there is checkbox which is selected when ItemClick happens.
Now WHen User does a long click, I am still getting a ItemClick which selects the checkbox and this looks odd as the user is trying to do something else.

How to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Set an [OnItemLongClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview) for your list view.

```
 getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            /*Make sure to return true so that the event will be consumed here, and not 
              propogated to the onListItemClick listener.*/

            return true;
        }
    });
```

See similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview).