# ListView OnLongClickListener doesn't works

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I wanna change background color of a `ListView`, but doesn't work with the listener `OnLongClickListener`.

The listener `OnItemLongClickListener` works but why `OnLongClickListener` no?

Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*
        etc..
    */
    ListView lv = (ListView)ret.findViewById(R.id.lun_list);
    lv.setAdapter(oa);
    lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            showPopup();
            return false;
        }
    });
    lv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            showTest();
            return false;
        }
    });

    return ret;
}
private void showTest(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    getView().findViewById(R.id.lun_list).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

Comment: try to return true instead of false in setOnLongClickListener() method and see

Comment: Here you have an answear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview

Comment: doesn't works with return true
@EliaszKubala I want click out of the items in a ListView

Answer (score 0):

have you added the following attribute to your list view to handle `OnLongClickListener` 
please set `android:longClickable="true"`

Comment: I dont inserted that, with that anyway doesn't works

Comment: are you use ListActivity or normal Acitity

Comment: I'm in a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, the MainActivity is a `FragmentActivity`

Comment: Please use the following code instead of OnLongClickListener use  list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int arg2, long arg3) {

}
});

Comment: I don't need an event for an `ITEM CLICK`, i need to click out of the items of the `ListView`. In Debug I click in the `ListView` but `OUT the items`, it doesn't works.

Comment: you couldn't click out of the items because listview is group of items in another word if you didn't set items inside listview you didn't have listview so you should deal with listview as a group of items and handle click on items

Comment: i set this solution to quick your work instead of searching on it and the following is document for what i say  Here is the link for the Android Docs for this method.[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29)

Comment: I avoided the problem, in another method. Anyway solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `listView.setLongClickable(true)` in java code or add the attribute `android:longClickable:"true"` to the ListView in the xml Layout file

Answer (score 0):

**Avoided the problem:**

I set the `ListView` in WrapContent Height, so now i can add a `OnLongClickListener` in the Background of the `Fragment` and do my events.