# OptionList On LongClick

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a expandable ListView with a bunch of ingredients selected by the user.

```
  exp = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        ing_cat = DataProvider.getInfo();
        ing_list = new ArrayList<String>(ing_cat.keySet());
        indicator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        adpt = new MyIngAdapter(this, ing_cat, ing_list);
        exp.setAdapter(adpt);
        int noOfGroups = exp.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount();
```

Now on clicking one of the views of the ListView I would like an option to come asking remove as shown below in the picture(On Long Click This Opened):

[image]

I want something Similar to this, where I can put my own methods. Could someone please help me out.

Thanks
Kalyan

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview