# listview setOnItemLongClickListerer didnt work

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement onItemLongClickListener and onItemClickListener event on listview row but the problem is that when I longPress the listview row and release it then both events get called at the same time. Please give me solution how can I achive this.

here is my code

```
listregional.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final CharSequence[] dialogregion = {"Edit","Delete"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Pilih Menu");
        builder.setItems(dialogregion, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int region) {
                switch (region){
                    case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Edited",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

        return false;
    }
});
```

please help me

Comment: Return `true` from the `onItemLongClick()` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview

Answer (score 1):

```
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// your code
return true
}
```

`return true` instead of `return false` will prevent click event to be continue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to signal other listeners that the dispatched event is consumed by returning true

Answer (score 0):

Return `boolean true`:

```
 listregional.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final CharSequence[] dialogregion = {"Edit","Delete"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Pilih Menu");
            builder.setItems(dialogregion, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int region) {
                   switch (region){
                       case 0:
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Edited",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           break;
                       case 1:
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           break;
                   }
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling long press events is essentially the same as handling clicks except that you return a boolean which specifies whether Android should continue to propagate the click event.

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id){
    return onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id);
}
```

});

If your long-click method returns true then you are telling Android that you handled the event. If your method returns false, Android will still call other handlers such as your onItemClick handler.

```
protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, int pos, long id) {
Log.i(TAG, "onLongListItemClick id=" + id);
return true;
```

}

so change the last line of your code to return TRUE.