# How to handle Long press event in accessibility in android

Tags: android, accessibility

How to handle Long press event in accessibility in android?
Also how can I detect focus on an specific view/element in accessibility?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after analysis it is identified that In accessibility all the gestures are by using two fingers. Single finger touch and swipe are overriden by android for accessibility.