# OnItemClick isn't working on a ListView item

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a custom layout for the list's cells where you have a checkbox and 3 text elements. I found on Stackoverflow that I should add `android:descendantFocusability = "blocksDescendants"` on my LinearLayout where the list is but it doesn't change anything.

Here is my XML for the page with the list :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl_fragment_detail_apero"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.home.AperoDetailFragment"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_apero"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_apero"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#DDDDDD" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_shopping_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:text="@string/shopping_list_title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_ingredients"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:text="@string/btn_add_ingredient"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_ingredient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

then in my Java code I set the listener like this :

```java
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_apero, container, false);
        final TextView name = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.name_apero);
        name.setText(detailApero.name);
        TextView date = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.date_apero);
        date.setText(detailApero.date);
// some code that aren't useful right now
        //-------------- List of ingredients for the detailed apero
        final ListView list_ingredient = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_ingredient);

        LaperoDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(root.getContext(),
                LaperoDatabase.class, "lapero_db").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        IngredientDao dbIngredient = db.getIngredientDao();

        //@TODO control if we get the right ingredients
        ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredient_of_this_apero = (ArrayList<Ingredient>) dbIngredient.getIngredientsFromApero(detailApero.aid);

        IngredientAdapter adapter = new IngredientAdapter(root.getContext(), R.layout.ingredient_cell_layout, ingredient_of_this_apero);
        list_ingredient.setAdapter(adapter);
        list_ingredient.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                Ingredient selected_ingredient = (Ingredient) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.e("test","okasodkdaso");
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

I also tried using a `OnItemLongClickListener` but it also does nothing. How can I put a listener for the list items ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8846824/10778405). there is answer as you want.

Comment: yes it's right thank you ! how can I mark this as an answer ?